# program timeout in windows for python

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout

Hi I've seen a bunch of questions here on SE that deal with similar issues but I find much of the answers to be unclear and confusing. My question is very simple. How on a Windows platform can I kill a running function after a certain amount of time using Python v2.6? If I have:

```
def my_function(start):
    x=start
    while True:
        print x
        x=x+1
    return x
```

how can I have this stop after X seconds? Please keep your answers clear about where to put in my function and how to adjust the time limit. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to run a normal function with a timeout, try:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from time import sleep

endtime = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(seconds = 2)

while True:
    sleep(1) # just an example
    if datetime.utcnow() > endtime: # if more than two seconds has elapsed
        break
```

If you're talking about stopping a thread, there is a blog post about doing this with threads which covers all the bases.

[How (not) to set a timeout on a computation in Python](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/22/how-not-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-computation-in-python/). The [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky) also uses this site.

Basically, the answer is that there is no "right way" to do this in Python, though if you're not on Windows `SIGALARM` works.

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward solution:

Have a look at the datetime module. You can save a timestamp upon start of the loop and calculate the timedelta in the while part.

If the timedelta is greater then the one you wish to have, break from the loop by calling "break".

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use this [timeout.py](http://code.google.com/p/verse-quiz/source/browse/trunk/timeout.py) module to your advantage. Its use requires that a function be written and passed through (or decorated with) the `add_timeout` function in the module.

```
import timeout

def my_function(start):
    x=start
    while True:
        print x
        x=x+1
    return x

my_function = timeout.add_timeout(my_function, seconds)
```

After calling the new "function," you can query the `ready` property to find out its state of exection:

- `False` means the function is still executing.
- `True` means that execution has ended.
- `None` means that the timeout has been reached and the function terminated.

If and when `ready` is `True`, the `value` property will have the results of the functions execution. If the function raised an exception, it will be re-raised upon evaluating `value`. If `value` is evaluated before `ready` is `True`, a `timeout.NotReadyError` will be raised.

**Note:** the module was not designed specifically for decorating functions, and methods in general *should not* be decorated. Instance attributes are not guaranteed to be updated across the execution boundary.

---

**Addendum:**

It appears that Google Code does not support looking up the [timeout.py](http://code.google.com/p/verse-quiz/source/browse/trunk/timeout.py) module anymore. Although the API is a little different, I would recommend the `asynchronous` module instead. Its source is included below followed by a second module used to verify it is working correctly.

**asynchronous.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import abc as _abc
import collections as _collections
import enum as _enum
import math as _math
import multiprocessing as _multiprocessing
import operator as _operator
import queue as _queue
import signal as _signal
import sys as _sys
import time as _time

__all__ = (
    'Executor',
    'get_timeout',
    'set_timeout',
    'submit',
    'map_',
    'shutdown'
)


class _Base(metaclass=_abc.ABCMeta):
    __slots__ = (
        '__timeout',
    )

    @_abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, timeout):
        self.timeout = _math.inf if timeout is None else timeout

    def get_timeout(self):
        return self.__timeout

    def set_timeout(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, (float, int)):
            raise TypeError('value must be of type float or int')
        if value <= 0:
            raise ValueError('value must be greater than zero')
        self.__timeout = value

    timeout = property(get_timeout, set_timeout)


def _run_and_catch(fn, args, kwargs):
    # noinspection PyPep8,PyBroadException
    try:
        return False, fn(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        return True, _sys.exc_info()[1]


def _run(fn, args, kwargs, queue):
    queue.put_nowait(_run_and_catch(fn, args, kwargs))


class _State(_enum.IntEnum):
    PENDING = _enum.auto()
    RUNNING = _enum.auto()
    CANCELLED = _enum.auto()
    FINISHED = _enum.auto()
    ERROR = _enum.auto()


def _run_and_catch_loop(iterable, *args, **kwargs):
    exception = None
    for fn in iterable:
        error, value = _run_and_catch(fn, args, kwargs)
        if error:
            exception = value
    if exception:
        raise exception


class _Future(_Base):
    __slots__ = (
        '__queue',
        '__process',
        '__start_time',
        '__callbacks',
        '__result'
    )

    def __init__(self, timeout, fn, args, kwargs):
        super().__init__(timeout)
        self.__queue = _multiprocessing.Queue(1)
        self.__process = _multiprocessing.Process(
            target=_run,
            args=(fn, args, kwargs, self.__queue),
            daemon=True
        )
        self.__start_time = _math.inf
        self.__callbacks = _collections.deque()
        self.__result = True, TimeoutError()

    @property
    def __state(self):
        pid, exitcode = self.__process.pid, self.__process.exitcode
        return (_State.PENDING if pid is None else
                _State.RUNNING if exitcode is None else
                _State.CANCELLED if exitcode == -_signal.SIGTERM else
                _State.FINISHED if exitcode == 0 else
                _State.ERROR)

    def __repr__(self):
        root = f'{type(self).__name__} at {id(self)} state={self.__state.name}'
        if self.__state < _State.CANCELLED:
            return f'<{root}>'
        error, value = self.__result
        suffix = f'{"raised" if error else "returned"} {type(value).__name__}'
        return f'<{root} {suffix}>'

    def __consume_callbacks(self):
        while self.__callbacks:
            yield self.__callbacks.popleft()

    def __invoke_callbacks(self):
        self.__process.join()
        _run_and_catch_loop(self.__consume_callbacks(), self)

    def cancel(self):
        self.__process.terminate()
        self.__invoke_callbacks()

    def __auto_cancel(self):
        elapsed_time = _time.perf_counter() - self.__start_time
        if elapsed_time > self.timeout:
            self.cancel()
        return elapsed_time

    def cancelled(self):
        self.__auto_cancel()
        return self.__state is _State.CANCELLED

    def running(self):
        self.__auto_cancel()
        return self.__state is _State.RUNNING

    def done(self):
        self.__auto_cancel()
        return self.__state > _State.RUNNING

    def __handle_result(self, error, value):
        self.__result = error, value
        self.__invoke_callbacks()

    def __ensure_termination(self):
        elapsed_time = self.__auto_cancel()
        if not self.__queue.empty():
            self.__handle_result(*self.__queue.get_nowait())
        elif self.__state < _State.CANCELLED:
            remaining_time = self.timeout - elapsed_time
            if remaining_time == _math.inf:
                remaining_time = None
            try:
                result = self.__queue.get(True, remaining_time)
            except _queue.Empty:
                self.cancel()
            else:
                self.__handle_result(*result)

    def result(self):
        self.__ensure_termination()
        error, value = self.__result
        if error:
            raise value
        return value

    def exception(self):
        self.__ensure_termination()
        error, value = self.__result
        if error:
            return value

    def add_done_callback(self, fn):
        if self.done():
            fn(self)
        else:
            self.__callbacks.append(fn)

    def _set_running_or_notify_cancel(self):
        if self.__state is _State.PENDING:
            self.__process.start()
            self.__start_time = _time.perf_counter()
        else:
            self.cancel()


class Executor(_Base):
    __slots__ = (
        '__futures',
    )

    def __init__(self, timeout=None):
        super().__init__(timeout)
        self.__futures = set()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        future = _Future(self.timeout, fn, args, kwargs)
        self.__futures.add(future)
        future.add_done_callback(self.__futures.remove)
        # noinspection PyProtectedMember
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        return future

    @staticmethod
    def __cancel_futures(iterable):
        _run_and_catch_loop(map(_operator.attrgetter('cancel'), iterable))

    def map(self, fn, *iterables):
        futures = tuple(self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables))

        def result_iterator():
            future_iterator = iter(futures)
            try:
                for future in future_iterator:
                    yield future.result()
            finally:
                self.__cancel_futures(future_iterator)

        return result_iterator()

    def shutdown(self):
        self.__cancel_futures(frozenset(self.__futures))

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.shutdown()
        return False


_executor = Executor()
get_timeout = _executor.get_timeout
set_timeout = _executor.set_timeout
submit = _executor.submit
map_ = _executor.map
shutdown = _executor.shutdown
del _executor
```

**test_asynchronous.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import _thread
import atexit
import functools
import inspect
import io
import math
import operator
import os
import sys
import time
import unittest

import asynchronous


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestConstructor:
    def instantiate(self, *args):
        parameters = len(inspect.signature(self.CLASS).parameters)
        return self.CLASS(*args[:parameters])

    def test_valid_timeout(self):
        instance = self.instantiate(None, print, (), {})
        self.assertEqual(instance.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        instance = self.instantiate(1, print, (), {})
        self.assertEqual(instance.get_timeout(), 1)
        float_timeout = (math.e ** (1j * math.pi) + 1).imag
        self.assertIsInstance(float_timeout, float)
        instance = self.instantiate(float_timeout, print, (), {})
        self.assertEqual(instance.get_timeout(), float_timeout)

    def test_error_timeout(self):
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.instantiate, '60', print, (), {})
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.instantiate, 0, print, (), {})
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.instantiate, -1, print, (), {})


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestTimeout(TestConstructor):
    def test_valid_property(self):
        instance = self.instantiate(None, None, None, None)
        instance.timeout = 1
        self.assertIsInstance(instance.timeout, int)
        instance.timeout = 1 / 2
        self.assertIsInstance(instance.timeout, float)
        kilo_bit = int.from_bytes(os.urandom(1 << 7), 'big')
        instance.timeout = kilo_bit
        self.assertEqual(instance.timeout, kilo_bit)

    def test_error_property(self):
        instance = self.instantiate(None, None, None, None)
        for exception, value in (
                (TypeError, 'inf'),
                (TypeError, complex(123456789, 0)),
                (ValueError, 0),
                (ValueError, 0.0),
                (ValueError, -1),
                (ValueError, -math.pi)
        ):
            with self.assertRaises(exception):
                instance.timeout = value
            self.assertEqual(instance.timeout, math.inf)


class Timer:
    __timers = {}

    @classmethod
    def start_timer(cls):
        ident, now = _thread.get_ident(), time.perf_counter()
        if now is not cls.__timers.setdefault(ident, now):
            raise KeyError(ident)

    @classmethod
    def stop_timer(cls, expected_time, error=None):
        if error is None:
            error = 1 / 4  # the default is a quarter second
        used = time.perf_counter() - cls.__timers.pop(_thread.get_ident())
        diff = used - expected_time
        return -error <= diff <= +error


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestTimer(Timer):
    def stop_timer(self, expected_time, error=None):
        self.assertTrue(super().stop_timer(expected_time, error))


def delay_run(delay, fn, *args, sync=True, **kwargs):
    def wrapper():
        time.sleep(delay)
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    if sync:
        return wrapper()
    _thread.start_new_thread(wrapper, ())


# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
class TestModuleOrInstance(TestTimer):
    @property
    def moi(self):
        return self.MODULE_OR_INSTANCE

    def test_valid_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(math.inf)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        self.moi.set_timeout(60)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), 60)
        self.moi.set_timeout(0.05)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), 0.05)

    def test_error_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(math.inf)
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, self.moi.set_timeout, None)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.moi.set_timeout, 0)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, self.moi.set_timeout, -1)
        self.assertEqual(self.moi.get_timeout(), math.inf)

    def run_submit_check(self):
        self.start_timer()
        future = self.moi.submit(delay_run, 0.5, operator.add, 1, 2)
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=RUNNING>$')
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=FINISHED returned int>$'
        )

    def test_submit_one_second_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1)
        self.run_submit_check()

    def test_submit_no_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(math.inf)
        self.run_submit_check()

    def test_submit_short_timeout(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(0.5)
        self.start_timer()
        future = self.moi.submit(delay_run, 1, operator.add, 1, 2)
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=RUNNING>$')
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=CANCELLED raised TimeoutError>$'
        )

    def run_map(self, *args):
        return getattr(self.moi, self.NAME_OF_MAP)(delay_run, *args)

    def test_valid_map(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        for result in self.run_map(
                [1, 1, 1, 1],
                [operator.add] * 4,
                [0, 1, 2, 3],
                [3, 2, 1, 0]
        ):
            self.assertEqual(result, 3)

    def test_error_map(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        success = 0
        with self.assertRaises(TimeoutError):
            for result in self.run_map(
                    [1, 1, 2, 1],
                    [operator.add] * 4,
                    [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    [3, 2, 1, 0]
            ):
                self.assertEqual(result, 3)
                success += 1
        self.assertEqual(success, 2)

    def run_shutdown_check(self, running, future):
        self.assertRaises(TimeoutError, future.result)
        running.remove(future)

    def run_submit_loop(self, executor):
        running = set()
        done_callback = functools.partial(self.run_shutdown_check, running)
        for _ in range(10):
            future = executor.submit(delay_run, 2, operator.add, 10, 20)
            running.add(future)
            future.add_done_callback(done_callback)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        return running

    def test_valid_shutdown(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        running = self.run_submit_loop(self.moi)
        self.moi.shutdown()
        self.assertFalse(running)

    def test_error_shutdown(self):
        self.moi.set_timeout(1.5)
        running = self.run_submit_loop(self.moi)
        running.pop()
        self.assertRaises(KeyError, self.moi.shutdown)
        self.assertFalse(running)


class TestExecutorAPI(TestTimeout, TestModuleOrInstance, unittest.TestCase):
    CLASS = asynchronous.Executor
    MODULE_OR_INSTANCE = CLASS()
    NAME_OF_MAP = 'map'

    def test_valid_context_manager(self):
        with self.instantiate(1.5) as executor:
            running = self.run_submit_loop(executor)
        self.assertFalse(running)

    def test_error_context_manager(self):
        error = Exception()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            with self.instantiate(1.5) as executor:
                running = self.run_submit_loop(executor)
                raise error
        self.assertIs(cm.exception, error)
        self.assertFalse(running)
        with self.assertRaises(KeyError):
            with self.instantiate(1.5) as executor:
                running = self.run_submit_loop(executor)
                running.pop()
        self.assertFalse(running)


class TestModuleAPI(TestModuleOrInstance, unittest.TestCase):
    MODULE_OR_INSTANCE = asynchronous
    NAME_OF_MAP = 'map_'


def verify_error():
    sys.stderr.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
    for line in sys.stderr:
        if line == 'queue.Full\n':
            break
    else:
        sys.stderr.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        sys.__stderr__.write(sys.stderr.read())
        sys.__stderr__.flush()


def cause_error(obj):
    sys.stderr = io.StringIO()
    atexit.register(verify_error)
    inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_back.f_locals['queue'].put_nowait(obj)


def return_(obj):
    return obj


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def throw(exception, *args):
    raise exception


class TestFutureAPI(TestTimer, TestTimeout, unittest.TestCase):
    CLASS = asynchronous._Future

    def test_valid_representation(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=PENDING>$')
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRegex(repr(future), r'^<_Future at \d+ state=RUNNING>$')
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=CANCELLED raised TimeoutError>$'
        )
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=FINISHED raised TimeoutError>$'
        )
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=FINISHED returned NoneType>$'
        )

    def test_error_representation(self):
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, cause_error, (None,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRaises(TypeError, future.result)
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=ERROR raised TimeoutError>$'
        )
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, cause_error, ((False, 'okay'),), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 'okay')
        self.assertRegex(
            repr(future),
            r'^<_Future at \d+ state=ERROR returned str>$'
        )

    def test_cancel(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertRaises(AttributeError, future.cancel)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        checker = set()
        future.add_done_callback(checker.add)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertIs(checker.pop(), future)
        self.assertFalse(checker)

    def test_cancelled(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.cancelled())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertFalse(future.cancelled())
        self.assertIs(future.result(), None)
        self.assertFalse(future.cancelled())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, time.sleep, (1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())

    def test_running(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.running())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.running())
        self.assertIs(future.result(), None)
        self.assertFalse(future.running())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        future.cancel()
        self.assertFalse(future.running())
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, time.sleep, (1,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.assertFalse(future.running())

    def test_done(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.done())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertFalse(future.done())
        self.assertIs(future.result(), None)
        self.assertTrue(future.done())
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (None,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TypeError)
        self.assertTrue(future.done())

    def test_result_immediate(self):
        data = os.urandom(1 << 20)
        future = self.instantiate(None, return_, (data,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), data)
        test_exception = Exception('test')
        future = self.instantiate(None, throw, (test_exception,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            future.result()
        self.assertIsInstance(cm.exception, type(test_exception))
        self.assertEqual(cm.exception.args, test_exception.args)

    def test_result_delay(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 5)
        self.stop_timer(1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertRaises(TimeoutError, future.result)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_result_before_running(self):
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        delay_run(0.5, future._set_running_or_notify_cancel, sync=False)
        self.start_timer()
        self.assertEqual(future.result(), 3)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_exception_immediate(self):
        data = os.urandom(1 << 20)
        future = self.instantiate(None, return_, (data,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        test_exception = Exception('test')
        future = self.instantiate(None, throw, (test_exception,), {})
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), type(test_exception))
        self.assertEqual(future.exception().args, test_exception.args)

    def test_exception_delay(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(None, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(0.1)
        future = self.instantiate(0.5, delay_run, (1, operator.add, 2, 3), {})
        self.start_timer()
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIsInstance(future.exception(), TimeoutError)
        self.assertFalse(future.exception().args)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_exception_before_running(self):
        future = self.instantiate(0.1, delay_run, (0, operator.add, 1, 2), {})
        delay_run(0.5, future._set_running_or_notify_cancel, sync=False)
        self.start_timer()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.stop_timer(0.5)

    def test_valid_add_done_callback(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0,), {})
        requires_callback = {future}
        future.add_done_callback(requires_callback.remove)
        self.assertIn(future, requires_callback)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertIs(future.exception(), None)
        self.assertFalse(requires_callback)
        requires_callback.add(future)
        future.add_done_callback(requires_callback.remove)
        self.assertFalse(requires_callback)

    def test_error_add_done_callback(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0,), {})
        requires_callback = [{future} for _ in range(10)]
        callbacks = [s.remove for s in requires_callback]
        error = Exception()
        callbacks.insert(5, functools.partial(throw, error))
        for fn in callbacks:
            future.add_done_callback(fn)
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            future.exception()
        self.assertIs(cm.exception, error)
        self.assertFalse(any(requires_callback))

    def test_set_running_or_notify_cancel(self):
        future = self.instantiate(None, time.sleep, (0.1,), {})
        self.assertFalse(future.running() or future.done())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.running())
        future._set_running_or_notify_cancel()
        self.assertTrue(future.cancelled())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: That's an interesting module, but quite a lot of overhead as it has to spawn a process to run the function -- it's also for running a function asynchronously (if I'm reading it right), not blocking, which is what I think the question was really about.

Comment: If Double AA does not mind even more overhead, a wrapper can be written around the `timeout` module such that the returned object is synchronous and possibly relies on an extra thread as well.